# Issue with Ms access Reports

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to preview a report of the current tracking number which is on the main form(main form name is:frmReviewReleaseLogWrapper) by using a command button.
Each tracking number has different part numbers, so each tracking number has many records in the DB table (Depending upon the number of partnumbers, that is each partnumber has a record)
I wrote the following code and it is not working, It is just displaying report name and column names and not the records.

Code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Command225_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command225_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptEventLog", acPreview, , "[TrackingNumber] = Forms!frmReviewReleaseLogWrapper"

Exit_Command225_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command225_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command225_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Using the ms-access tag is sufficient unless your problem is specific to a particular version of Access.  Even then I'd still use the ms-access tag.

Comment: And the reason to use the MS-ACCESS tag even when you have a version-specific question is because you want the maximum number of people with expertise in the subject to see your question. More people are going to search for MS-ACCESS than for any specific version of Access, so your question will be more widely seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the name of the control on the frmReviewReleaseLogWrapper form that contains the tracking number? You need to reference it in your OpenReport statement, like so:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptEventLog", acPreview, , _
    "[TrackingNumber] = Forms!frmReviewReleaseLogWrapper!txtField"
```

Incidentally, you might do better to give your command button a name that reflects its actual function, so it'll be easier to find later.